# Does the Variance have anything to do with measuring uncertainty?

Tags: variance, prediction, model, uncertainty

I have found that one way to  get the uncertainty of predictions.is to measure how much they differ (get the .var() of your predictions).

With this difference, you can then see what samples the model is ‘uncertain’ about (the ones with high variance)

I was wondering if is it true that we can meausure uncetainty using the Variance or how exactly we can measure uncertainty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variance is a fairly common measure of uncertainty. Entropy is also often used; in some cases they are equivalent. [This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215091936) goes into some detail on the topic. However, uncertainty can mean different things in different contexts, and choosing which measure to use depends on what you want to know. [From this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/is-variance-really-a-measure-of-uncertainty-6ec6da21bb03), one example would be that a discrete bimodal distribution might have a higher variance than a uniform distribution over the same range, but a lower entropy. That is, there are fewer values to choose from (so you can be more certain about the value any given sample will take), but the variance of the sample set will be high (because there will be a greater difference of all samples in the set from the mean of the set).